# Solution to $P_n(x)$=$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k}x^{k+1}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $P_n(x)$=$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k}(\frac {z}{\zeta_n})^{k+1}$, is an nth degree polynomial, $\forall (\zeta_n,z)\in\Bbb{C}$, then if $x=\frac {z}{\zeta_n}$, where $x\not=0$, what are the values of $\zeta_n$ that satisfy $P_n(x)$=$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k}x^{k+1}=0$? This is equivalent to finding the complex or real roots of an nth-degree polynomial of the form: $$a_n x^{n} + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + a_1x = 0$$, where $a_n=\frac{1}{n}, \forall n\in\Bbb{N}$.

Best Regards

Comment: Maybe this helps: $\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} x^k = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1 - t^n}{1-t}dt$

Comment: However, the solution to $P_n(x)$=$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac {1}{k}(\frac {z}{\zeta_n})^{k+1}$ would be $x=0$ or $\frac{z}{\zeta_n}=0$, which therefore implies that $\zeta_n$ is undefined. Is this correct? @Reactant

Comment: This likely has no closed form solution.